# Where should I set model fields derived from a form field?

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

Given a model with some fields which do not map directly to a `ModelForm`'s fields, where should I set their value? In the following, `form.blast_db` should be assigned to either `model.protein_db` or `model.nucleotide_db` depending on what type of blast DB it is. They are mutually exclusive but required, so they must be set before `model.full_clean()` is called.

```py
from django.db import models

class BlastQuery(models.Model):

    # Protein/nucleotide blast DB. Mutually exclusive, one must be provided
    protein_db = models.ForeignKey(ProteinDB, null=True, blank=True)
    nucleotide_db = models.ForeignKey(ProteinDB, null=True, blank=True)

    # Just 1 field to keep it terse but in reality there are many other fields
    foo = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.protein_db and self.nucleotide_db:
            raise ValidationError('Protein/nucleotide DB are mutually exclusive')
        if not self.protein_db and not self.nucleotide_db:
            raise ValidationError('Protein/nucleotide DB are required')
```

```py
from django import forms

class BlastForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # Magical field that's like a ModelChoiceField but can
    # hold both ProteinDB and NucleotideDB instances
    blast_db = BlastDBField()

    class Meta:
        model = BlastQuery
        fields = ('foo',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the derived fields in `Form.clean`:

```
class BlastForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # ...

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        # Validate/modify self.cleaned_data
        # ...
        
        # Derive the protein/nucleotide db field
        blast_db = self.cleaned_data.get('blast_db')
        if blast_db:
            if blast_db.type == 'protein':
                self.instance.protein_db = blast_db
            else:
                self.instance.nucleotide_db = blast_db
```

`ModelForm` updates `self.instance` with `self.cleaned_data` after `form.clean()` (in `_post_clean`) and calls `model.full_clean()` so if you were to change `self.instance` in `form.save()`, you would be too late to prevent the validation error. Also note that only `Meta.fields` which do not appear in `Meta.exclude` are applied from `self.cleaned_data` to `self.instance`, so setting `protein_db`/`nucleotide_db` in `self.cleaned_data` won't do anything either. You could override [Model.clean_fields(exclude)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields) instead of `Model.clean` and skip validation of `protein_db` and `nucleotide_db` when they are in `exclude`, but then they will never be validated unless you call `form.full_clean()` again before saving it. Hence just set it in `Form.clean` as it has none of these downsides.